# Fixed Row and Column in a grid - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build a grid, with the first row fixed during vertically scroll, and the first column fixed during horizontally scroll

[image: like this]

**Do you know any plugin/component to achieve this ?**

Actually for this I use 3 scrollView :

- One for the fixed row, with only horizontal scroll
- One for the fixed column, with only vertical scroll
- One for the other cell, with horizontal and vertical scroll.

Then I have to synchronize the scrollViews, to be sure the alignment is preserved.

This is really ugly to do, and it might be laggy with all this synchronizations...

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0">

                    <ScrollView 
                        x:Name="ScrollEnteteSynthese"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Scrolled="ScrollEnteteSynthese_Scrolled"
                        >
                        <Grid
                            x:Name="gridEnteteSynthese"
                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Grey}"
                            ColumnSpacing="1"
                            RowSpacing="1"
                            />

                    </ScrollView>

                    <StackLayout
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Spacing="0"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                >

                        <ScrollView 
                            x:Name="ScrollColSynthese"
                            Orientation="Vertical"
                            Scrolled="ScrollColSynthese_Scrolled"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            WidthRequest="100">

                            <Grid
                                x:Name="gridColSynthese"
                                ColumnSpacing="1"
                                RowSpacing="1"
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Grey}"
                                />
                        </ScrollView>


                        <ScrollView 
                            x:Name="ScrollSynthese"
                            Orientation="Both"
                            Scrolled="ScrollSynthese_Scrolled"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    >

                            <Grid
                                x:Name="gridSynthese"
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource GreyLight}"
                                ColumnSpacing="1"
                                RowSpacing="1"
                                        />
                        </ScrollView>
                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>
```

Comment: check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793709/mixed-fixed-and-scrollable-elements-on-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are many different layout can implement it. For example

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <Grid HeightRequest="300" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="350" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Padding="0">
            <ScrollView BackgroundColor="LightBlue"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    //...
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </Frame>

        <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Padding="0" Margin="0,-5,0,0">
            <ScrollView BackgroundColor="LightGreen"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    //...
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </Frame>
        <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Padding="0" Margin="-5,-5,0,0">
            <Grid  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightPink">

                 //

           </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Why do you use Frames ? I dont know much about this layout. And how do you syncrhonize scrollviews ? To be sure when u scroll the cells, the header also scroll. Actually i did it on Scrolled event, but seems to take a lot of ressources

Comment: Otherwise it will have white space between grid cell .